# Is it possible to make page breaks so everything is formatted when I view the PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

```
    Sub pagesetuptrythis()
'
' pagesetuptrythis Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:L1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=173
    Range("A1:L195").Select
    With ActiveSheet.pagesetup
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
        .PrintTitleColumns = ""
    End With
    ActiveSheet.pagesetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$195"
    With ActiveSheet.pagesetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = ""
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = ""
        .CenterFooter = ""
        .RightFooter = ""
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .PrintHeadings = False
        .PrintGridlines = False
        .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
        .PrintQuality = -4
        .CenterHorizontally = False
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlPortrait
        .Draft = False
        .PaperSize = 0
        .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
        .Order = xlDownThenOver
        .BlackAndWhite = False
        .Zoom = 100
    End With
    ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=112
    Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(2).Location = Range("A132")
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-63
    Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A62")
End Sub
```

Using Excel for Mac.

I am trying to shift the page break to the right, so that the blue vertical line is between L and M. I am then adjusting the horizontal page breaks, so that the text is not cut off, when I go to save.

Unfortunately this does not work, and when I click debug, a yellow arrow/highlighter appears over `ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1` and will not proceed any further.

Is it possible to make the macro perform the page breaks, so everything is formatted when I view the PDF?